# I have a problem with my middleware in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I have a problem with my middleware, there is a line that I lose the CSS styles and the JS interactivity in my webpages when I  uncomment it. I don't know why, the middleware.js is like that:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || "";
  const isPublic = path == "/signup" || path == "/login";
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  if (!token && !isPublic) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url)); //this line
  }
  if (token && isPublic) {
    console.log("the path is if: ", path);
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/profile", request.url));
  }
  return response;
}
```

I already removed the line and everything worked well, but I need this checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a `middleware` by default runs for every request, including the ones for getting assets such as JavaScript, CSS, and image files.  As you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matching-paths):

> Middleware will be invoked for **every route in your project**. The following is the execution order:
>
> 1. `headers` from `next.config.js`
> 2. `redirects` from `next.config.js`
> 3. Middleware (`rewrites`, `redirects`, etc.)
> 4. `beforeFiles` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`
> 5. Filesystem routes (`public/`, `_next/static/`, `pages`, etc.)
> 6. `afterFiles` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`
> 7. Dynamic Routes (`/blog/[slug]`)
> 8. `fallback` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`

With that `NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url))`, you are basically sending the login page, when the browser requests say `main.css`.

To have it execute for some paths only, you need to use [conditional statements](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#conditional-statements) or the [`matcher`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher) object, like so:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

/**
 * This middleware runs based on the config below, 
 * instead of running for every request.
 */
export function middleware(request) {
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};
```

Comment: i think your right bro, i'm trying to change the middleware, to match only the requested paths, and i will tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, which is the matcher wasn't compare the requests, so when i added the regex matcher everything works fine